# Displaying categories in sql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create only one table for the categories. I don't want to create other tables for the parent-child. All the categories should be stored in a single table.
Add/Update/Delete categories.The category name should be unique. If any parent category is deleted all the child categories (if exists) should be also deleted.
If there are already categories created, a new category can be a subcategory of any category or main category. If any category is created, then form shall have an option to make that category as a parent category.For example:

```
-> House
    -> Flat
        -> 2BHK Flat
            -> 2BHK Flat 1200 sq ft
                -> 2BHK Flat 1200 sq ft on 4th floor
                -> 2BHK Flat 1200 sq ft on 10th floor
                    -> 2BHK Flat 1200 sq ft on 10th floor with two balconies
                    -> 2BHK Flat 1200 sq ft on 10th floor with 5 balconies
```

In the end, I want to display all the categories in a tabular format, show the parent category (if exist)

Example

```
ID:         Category                Parent Category
=======================================================
1.          Flat                        ----
2.          2BHK Flat                   Flat
3.          2BHK Flat 1200 sq ft        2BHK Flat
```

What would be the query for such categories?

Comment: You want to use a hierarchical query. Depending on the database with which you're working (mysql, oracle), the syntax would change.

Comment: I want in mysql..Can you plz help me out?

Comment: Sounds a lot like "can someone do my homework"....?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far and explain how that failed to accomplish the goal?

Answer (score -1):

Prepare categories data in array format and use below approach for insertion

```
//Prepare a category tree
    public function categoryTree()
    {
        $categoriesData = [];
        $arr =  [
            "House" => [
                "Flat" => [
                    "2BHK Flat" => [
                        "2BHK Flat 1200 sq ft" => [
                            "2BHK Flat 1200 sq ft on 4th floor" => [],
                            "2BHK Flat 1200 sq ft on 10th floor" => [
                                "2BHK Flat 1200 sq ft on 10th floor with two balconies" => [],
                                "2BHK Flat 1200 sq ft on 10th floor with 5 balconies" => []
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];

        self::displayCategories($arr, $categoriesData);
    }

 //insertion of categories in db
 public static function displayCategories($arr, $categoriesData) 
 {
    foreach($arr as $parentCat => $childCat) {
        $categoriesData[] = "('{$parentCat}', '".implode(',', array_keys($childCat))."')";
        if(!empty($childCat)) {
            self::displayCategories($childCat, $categoriesData);
        }
    }

    INSERT INTO `table_name` (`Parent_Category`,`Category`) VALUES .implode(',', $categoriesData);
 }

 //Deletion of categories 
  public static function categoryDeletion($parentCategory) 
  {
      DELETE FROM `table_name` WHERE `Parent_Category` = '{$parentCategory}';
  }
```